# memory mapped data not comming correctly

Tags: c++, boost

I have written a code where i am writing a map in a binary file and than reading it using boost memory mapping, but whenever i display the result it is not correct it only shows value as

> 1852795252

. what should i do? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

using namespace boost::archive;
using namespace boost::interprocess;
void save()
{
    {
        std::ofstream file{"archive1.bin"};
        text_oarchive oa{file};
        std::map<int,int> m;
        m[3] = 9;  
        oa << m;
    }
}

void load()
{
    file_mapping fm("archive1.bin", read_only);
    mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
    int * m = (int *)region.get_address();
    std::cout<<m[3]<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  save();
  load();
}
```

Comment: When you tried to debug your program, what were your findings?

Comment: i couldn't find anything, it shows no error or warning msgs.

Comment: Now I have little idea about the libraries you are using here, but I am surprised that you think you can serialize a `std::map` to a file and then read it back as if it was an array. That seems suspicious to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not writing to `archive1.bin` what you think you are writing.  This can be demonstrated by adding the lines:

```
text_oarchive oa2 {std::cout};
oa2 << m;
```

at the end of function `save`, and when you do this you see:

> 22 serialization::archive 17 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 9

printed to `stdout`.

To clarify further, change the last line of function `load` to:

```
std::cout << std::hex << m[3] << std::endl;
```

and then you see:

> 6e6f6974

which is ASCII `noit`, i.e. the fourth integer in `archive1.bin`.

All of which is a long-winded way of saying what john says in his comment above.  You should read a boost archive using the [approved serialisation functions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4CqFyNOcKifPtp5n).

Comment: so how do i correctly write and read this value with memory mapping?

Comment: @asdf What is your outer problem? Because what you're trying to do just doesn't seem sensible and there's probably a sensible way to solve whatever problem you have. You're trying to write data out with one method and read it back in with a completely unrelated method which just won't work. It's like having a Spanish writer write a book and then having a French speaker try to read it. Why would you expect it to make sense to them? Boost serialization and memory mapped arrays are entirely unrelated.

Comment: well, its for 3d computer vision project, writing the map values are for saving the pattern of object while reading them is for pattern matching which happens in another program but right now i'm testing the function so... for that i'll be using key and value as string. so that how do i write the them?